# JHipster i18n appears to be broken

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

We have a JHipster microservices architecture application with a gateway and three microservices. A few months ago, we removed all the webapp/UI code from the gateway and created a separate repository with all of it. It seems we removed some important code that contributes to the localized error pages. If I go to localhost:9000/login (a page that doesn't exist), I get a page that says the following:

```
??error.title_en_US??
??error.subtitle_en_US??

??error.status_en_US?? Not Found (Not Found)
??error.message_en_US?? Not Found
```

What does this indicate that might be missing and needs to be added back in?

Comment: I don't see anything about i18n in the console.

Comment: Problem is only with error messages? Does it happen only when typing url in browser (i..e with full page reload) or does it happen also if add a broken link to a working page like home and you click on it? If it happens only on full page reload, it could be a problem on backend.

Comment: It appears the problem is only with error messages, yes.

Comment: and what about my other question?

Comment: It happens with links and with reloads.